# add "id" attribute to a table to reference it

Tags: html, xhtml

So it requires me to identify a table on a webpage. And there is no way I can think of I can do that from the table header that I have currently. So one way I can think of is to add an attribute by right click -> add an attribute. But as I right click on the HTML I have an option called add attribute. Sorry, bear with me as I am new to this. As I try to add the attribute id="something", it gets saved but when I refresh the page, it gets deleted every time. I tried with a value attribute. the same thing happened again. Is the method I am trying to use in order to add an attribute wrong? If so, why? As the option is given to do so, why wouldn't it let me add an attribute? And I also need a solution to add an attribute to the table header.
This is the header I have for the table that I need to add an attribute for:

```
<table class="cols-5 sticky-enabled sticky-table">

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the method I am trying to use in order to add an attribute wrong? If so, why?

1. You make an HTTP request to get an HTML document.
2. The browser converts the HTML document into a DOM.
3. You modify the DOM in memory.
4. You refresh the page, causing the browser to make a new HTTP request and you are back at step 1.

You never change the server to make it send different HTML (and it would be terrible if you could, imagine visiting `http://google.com`, editing the page and then everyone in the world seeing your edit!).

If you want your changes to persist between page loads, then you need to edit whatever code the server is using to generate the page (which could be a plain `.html` file on your hard disk).

Comment: Yes, that was what i thought at first. But why is the option given where you can add an attribute, if there is no point in doing that? since it was given was why i tried to do so and saw if it helped, but it did not

Comment: Because you can add it *in the live DOM* for use in the here and **now** (i.e. not after you refresh the page and get a new DOM).